# Activating a -c command

Tags: vimrc

I'm having a tough time passing this command into vim at startup:

```
$ vim sql_actions_avails.log \
   -c 'set ut=100 | set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("G")'
```

This command only seems to 'work' after I click on the vim window -- it doesn't work unless I manually interact with the page. Is there a way so that it will just 'tail' the file without me having to click the screen once?

Answer (score 1):

The `CursorHold` event will only trigger after the user has pressed a key, which hasn't yet happened when Vim is first opened.

(Once you're in the loop, it will trigger repeatedly, since `feedkeys("G")` will produce a "key" stroke, which will then trigger the event again after `'updatetime'` has elapsed.)

You can easily produce a keystroke at startup by also registering this same autocmd for the `VimEnter` event.

```
$ vim sql_actions_avails.log \
   -c 'set ut=100 autoread | au VimEnter,CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("G")'
```

Comment: hmm for some reason I get the same thing here -- it only triggers after I click into the window, but not before. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the window"... Are you using a GUI version of Vim? Is this on Windows? Or is this Vim on the terminal? More details would be helpful...

Comment: I'm on Mac -- I mean it doesn't `tail` automatically until I click into Vim (I suppose when it registers the cursor). I'm using normal vim